# Creating engine with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating an engine, and I have some problems.

I`m reading this [manual](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)

and my project has the following information:

- path to my main application: `/var/www/crs`
- path to my engine, myapp: `/var/www/crs/myapp`

These are the steps I tried:

1. I ran this code: `rails plugin new myapp --mountable`
2. I created the resource in `/var/www/crs/myapp/test/dummy/`
3. I added to `/var/www/crs/config/routes.rb` the line 
   `mount Myapp::Engine => "/myapp"`
4. I ran in the console (/var/www/crs/myapp/test/dummy/) this code: `rails s`

So far so good. However, when I added to the gem file in main app (/var/www/crs/Gemfile ) this line:

```
gem 'myapp', path: "myapp"
```

and executed the command

```
bundle
```

I got the following erros:

```
The gemspec at /var/www/crs/myapp/myapp.gemspec is not valid. The validation error was '"FIXME" or "TODO" is not a description'
Could not find gem 'myapp' in source at `myapp`.
Source does not contain any versions of 'myapp'
```

I don't understand where this error is comming from, nor do I know where the file that is having it is. How can I find the troublematic file and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried filling out the `gemspec` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `myapp.gemspec` is in your root folder of your engine.

in this file you write a short description (what does your engine does) and some dependecies e.g. the `myapp.gemspec` will be filled with default values when creating a gem (or a engine)

the configuration looks like the following

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "myengine"
  spec.version       = Myengine::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["my username"]
  spec.email         = ["my email"]
  spec.summary       = %q{ wow great engine }
  spec.description   = %q{ trust me, its a great engine which is great}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.7"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

and there you find the description with the TODO and FIXME message

btw Brandon Hilkert offers a really good tutorial about engines (http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/how-to-build-a-rails-engine/)